# search the existed hour using mysql and c# programming language

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I want is to search if the given hour already exists in the database I'm using MySQL database and c# programming language win.form.

```
string connection = "datasource=localhost;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
parking_reservation.bookedslots WHERE entryHour = 
'"+this.EntryHour.Value+"'", conDatabase);

        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdDatabase);

            sda.Fill(ds);
            int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already Booked");
                ds.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Booked Successfuly");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code above? Also you need to tell us more details. What is the datatype for the column _entryHour_ and what is the object _this.EntryHour_?

Comment: Your query seems to be vulnerable to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Nah the code actually worked silly me hahaha, now the real problem is that how to use  >= in MySQL query I really need it to search if the slot was already booked using the time in and time out thanks